# Wait() and NotifyAll()

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class SimpleConsumer extends Threads {
        public SyncQueue q;
        SimpleConsumer(SyncQueue q) { this.q = q; }
        public void run () { doit(); }
        public synchronized void doit() {
            while(true){
                try{
                    while(q.isEmpty()) { wait(); }
                    System.out.println((String)q.Dequeue());
                } 
                catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("Got exception:" +e); }
            }
        }    
    }
```

And I have another class that adds items to the same object SyncQueue and does notifyAll();

```
class SimpleProducer extends Threads {
public SyncQueue q;
SimpleProducer(SyncQueue q) { this.q = q; }
public void run() { doit(); }
public synchronized void doit() {
    while(true){
        try{
            sleep(1000);
            q.Enqueue("Item");
            notifyAll();
            } catch(Exception e) { System.out.println("Got exception:" +e); }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Will the SimpleConsumer wake up if I do notifyAll() from a different class method?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: SimpleConsumer did not wakeup...

Comment: You have to wait on the same object notifyAll is being called on. BTW Whatever you are trying to do would be simpler using an ExecutorService.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are waiting and notifying on 2 different objects - so they won't talk to each other. You need to use a common object and call the `wait` and `notifyAll` methods on that common object.

For example:

```
class SimpleConsumer extends Threads {
    private final SyncQueue q;

    SimpleConsumer(SyncQueue q) {
        this.q = q;
    }

    public void doit() {
        while(true){
            try{
                synchronized(q) {
                    while(q.isEmpty()) { q.wait(); }
                    System.out.println((String)q.Dequeue());
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("Got exception:" +e); }
        }
    }    
}
```

Note:

- I have made `q` private and final to make sure the reference is not changed externally.
- the monitor for the synchronized block in now the queue itself instead of `this`.

Comment: @OP Please note that this requires the synchronized blocks to use that object as a monitor as well (so: `synchronized (monitor) {` as opposed to declaring the method `synchronized`.

Comment: So, I can not do q.wait() in the consumer if I don't do the synchronized(q) block?

Comment: @TheNotMe When you call `someObject.wait()`, you need to be inside a `synchronized(someObject)` block or you will get an `IllegalMonitorException` at runtime. You should check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) which explains all that.